# In Xcode 12, In Info.plist file column expanding or resizing to zoom not working

Tags: xcode12, apple-developer

[image: For more details please see in reference image]

> For more information please see in reference image

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to 12.0.1?

Comment: Same thing on 12.0.1...

Comment: I have the same issue here. I can't scale it **Xcode 12.0.1**

Comment: Same issue on Xcode 12.1 GM Seed

Comment: Same issue on 12.2 . But for the love of all that is sacred. Dark mode.

Answer (score 120):

I had similar issue where the Value column was way too narrow.
I tried making the window as small as possible and then resizing, but that didn't help.
However, what seemed to resolve the issue for me was to click Add Editor on Right button (near the upper right corner with the "+") when Info.plist is displayed. This added a second window showing Info.plist with the Value column expanded all the way to the right edge, I closed the left pane with the narrow column.
Now, even after quitting or opening other projects, I get the Value column expanded all the way to the right edge.

- Steve

Answer (score 55):

I had the same problem too. I think this is a Xcode 12 bug. I solved this by:

- First open info.plist
- Click on show or hide code review button on top right corner. It will split the window.
- Again click the same button

I don't know how the problem is solved but it did.

[image]

Comment: I keep my xcode screens maximised so this solution is quick and easy to implement. Click click. Sorted.

Comment: worked like a charm.
some weird issue with 12

Answer (score 14):

I did manage to resize it after dragging the window bottom right border of the application window. Hope it helps anybody else struggling with it.

Comment: Dragging the window bottom right border of the application window - not working on "Type" and "Value" columns

Comment: @JitendraChauhan If you have a better alternative post your answer.

Comment: @JitendraChauhan Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't have any solution, 

Pressing_Keys_24_7, I have tried but not fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Try to add an editor (https://take.ms/V8fee) and then to close it.
It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Drag the bottom right corner and make the window as small as you can, and then drag it back to full size. That fixed it for me.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I meant this to be a comment, not an answer. It was late and I clicked the wrong button. It was meant to be a follow on to your answer as some people didn't think to shrink and then expand.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and I found a trick for XCode 12.2
just open the plist file and press the (+) button ( in the top right of the editor page) to appear right editor and press it again to disappear, it worked for me.

[image]